# php/laravel sending http request via curl error 500

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http, curl

when sending a HTTP request with curl, it's automatically changed to HTTPS request with 500 error.
I tried changing curl_option, but keeps crashing with error.

I want to send a header using a HTTP request through a cURL.
Would there be any other server setting issue or browser settings i need to check for ? 
I am using `apache2.4` & `php7.2` & `laravel7`
Please suggest

```
$ch = curl_init('http://test.site.com/test');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
dd($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel 7 ,you can use http client .Easy to find errors

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
```

post request like below.here `$params` is array

```
$htppCall = Http::post('http://test.site.com/test'',$params);
```

if you want to send headers then

```
 $htppCall= Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
       
    ])->get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",[]);
```

checking what status code you got

```
$htppCall->status()
```

to get data as object

```
$htppCall->object()
```

To get data as array

```
$htppCall->json()
```

To check client errors

```
$htppCall->clientError()
```

to check server errors

```
$htppCall->serverError()
```

To Get the body of the response.

```
 $htppCall->body()
```